# Replace superclass using IDEA SSR

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

I want to search for all classes extending `Foo` and make them extend `Bar` instead. The IDEA manual says this should work:

Search template

```
class $Class$ extends Foo {
    $Stuff$
}
```

Replace template

```
class $Class$ extends Bar {
    $Stuff$
}
```

where `$Stuff$` is configured to match zero to infinity times.

The search part works fine, but the replacement always has an empty class body. I tried setting `$Stuff$`'s minimum count to 1 and that still matches all the right classes, but the class body is still empty.

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me ... it always just replaces the class body with a blank. How did you get it to work?

Comment: @Strelok just seen now coz you haven't tagged me, anyway I didn't get that kind of a problem. worked for me perfectly. And you can see the official documentation too. And it has worked for jedediah too. Are you sure you did exactly the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

Search Template

```
class $Class$ extends Foo {}
```

Replace Template

```
class $Class$ extends Bar {}
```

No need to add `$Stuff$`.

You can find the examples documentation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html).